# Column Chart with DateTime on AxisX Displays wrong Dates

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, axis-labels

I created a column chart and I simply don't get the labels on the X-axis right.

Here is a screenshot of my chart. I added a line at the bottom of the screenshot to show how I expect it to be.

[image: Column Chart]

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string series = "TestData";

    // Clear Series
    chart.Series.Clear();

    // Add new Sereis and set XValueType
    chart.Series.Add(series);
    chart.Series[series].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;

    // Add data points to Series
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2008, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 49.91);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2009, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 102.05);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2010, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 15.84);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2011, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 29.12);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2012, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 3.3);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2013, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 31.09);
    chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2014, 12, 31).ToOADate(), 5.44);

    // Set color and dash style of Major Grid
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor       = Color.Gray;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle   = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor       = Color.Gray;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle   = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

    // Set Interval for X-Axis
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format         = "yyyy";
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval                  = 1;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType              = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
    chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType        = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
}
```

I already tried to use the `IntervalOffset`, but it did not do the job.

Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

Many thanks
Konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to change the Date to be the first day of the year and not the last, and you have to set the property IsXValueIndexed to true, like:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string series = "TestData";

        // Clear Series
        chart.Series.Clear();

        // Add new Sereis and set XValueType
        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.Series[series].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        chart.Series[series].IsXValueIndexed = true;

        // Add data points to Series
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2008, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 49.91);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2009, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 102.05);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 15.84);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2011, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 29.12);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2012, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 3.3);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2013, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 31.09);
        chart.Series[series].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1).ToOADate(), 5.44);

        // Set color and dash style of Major Grid
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;

        // Set Interval for X-Axis
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "yyyy";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Years;            

    }
```

Comment: I have an issue with sitting `IsXValueIndexed = true`. When I set the `AxisX.Minimum` to 01.01.2007 and `AxisX.Maximum` to 01.01.2015 the columns do not get plotted. As soon as I set `IsXValueIndexed = false` it works again. Do you have any idea why?